# What are Pageblocks and migrate types in Linux memory ? How many movable/unmovable pages are defined by default?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, configuration, memory

What are Pageblocks and migrate types in Linux memory ? How many movable/unmovable pages are defined by default?

With 2GB of memory, how many movable and unmovable pages are defined ?
Example -
cat /proc/pagetypeinfo :-
Kernel Version -  4.14 CPU Architecture - ARM 32-bit

```
Page block order: 12 
Pages per block:  4096

Free pages count per migrate type at order       0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11     12
Node    0, zone      DMA, type    Unmovable     71    235    137     30     17      7      2      0      0      1      1      0      0 
Node    0, zone      DMA, type      Movable      0      1      1      0      1      0      0      1      0      1      0      3      9  
Node    0, zone      DMA, type  Reclaimable      0      0      1      2      0      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      0 
Node    0, zone      DMA, type   HighAtomic      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0 
Node    0, zone      DMA, type          CMA      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0 
Node    0, zone      DMA, type      Isolate      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0 
Node    0, zone  HighMem, type    Unmovable     55     47     16      8      6      2      1      0      0      0      0      1      0 
Node    0, zone  HighMem, type      Movable      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0 
Node    0, zone  HighMem, type  Reclaimable      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0 
Node    0, zone  HighMem, type   HighAtomic      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0 
Node    0, zone  HighMem, type          CMA    261    915    778    204     48     20      5      0      0      0      0      1     13 
Node    0, zone  HighMem, type      Isolate      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0 


Number of blocks type     Unmovable      Movable  Reclaimable   HighAtomic          CMA      Isolate 

Node 0, zone      DMA           10           14            4            0            0            0     
Node 0, zone  HighMem            3           32            0            0           57            0
```

Comment: The kernel, distro, and release of Linux you use _could_ be relevant. For the kernel, do `uname -a`  .  Editing tips are at https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code .   Please click [edit] and add those three items to your question; please do not use Add Comment, instead, click [edit] .

Comment: @sourcejedi done